# Almost like Minecraft

Tags: riddle, word

You can take me apart and back together again,
But to do something useful you'll need a lot more than ten,
I come in all different colors, sizes, too,
And I’ve been in some movies, yes it’s true,
I’m in houses, sculptures and more,
I am even sometimes in a store,
Many people use me for fun,
And I can be used by anyone.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Lego Bricks

You can take me apart and back together again,

> Yup

But to do something useful you'll need a lot more than ten,

> You need more to build anything cool.

I come in all different colors, sizes, too,

> Duplo, regular.

And I’ve been in some movies,

> [Lego movie.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lego_Movie)

yes it’s true, I’m in houses, sculptures and more, I am even sometimes in a store,

> I guess.

Many people use me for fun, And I can be used by anyone.

> Fun for all ages! Even adults :)